# How can I get original elements in a class after groupBy in RxJava2?

Tags: java, json, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactivex

I have a list of JSON elements. Each JSON element is represented as Java class named "Foo" for example. This Foo class has others fields which are also a Java class. I am trying to group these Foo elements by Bar id and after that I want to do other operations on grouped elements like filter, sort.

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    private Bar bar;
    private Baz baz;
    private int qty;
}

public class Bar {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

public class Baz {
    private int id;
    private String type;
}
```

I tried something like this to see the result after groupBy operation but it didn't print anything. But if I provide simple elements like String or Integer instead of Foo and try to group those with the same approach, it works.

```
List<Foo> myInput = new ArrayList<>();
myInput.add(...);
myInput.add(...);
Observable.fromIterable(myInput)
                .groupBy(el -> el.getBar().getId())
                .concatMapSingle(Observable::toList)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This code works with this input and prints out grouped elements afterwards:

```
Observable<String> animals = Observable.just(
                "Tiger", "Elephant", "Cat", "Chameleon", "Frog", "Fish", "Flamingo");

animals.groupBy(animal -> animal.charAt(0))
                .concatMapSingle(Observable::toList)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(myInput)
                .filter(el -> el.getBaz().getType().equals("type1"))
                .groupBy(el -> el.getBar().getId())
                //.filter(...)
                //.sorted(...)
```

How can I group elements and retrieve that grouped elements and apply another operations on it? And could you also explain it a little bit so that I can understand what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `Observable#groupBy`:

> Groups the items emitted by an ObservableSource according to a specified criterion, and emits these grouped items as GroupedObservables.

From the docs of `GroupedObservable`:

> An Observable that has been grouped by key, the value of which can be obtained with getKey().

So, `GroupedObservable` is a subclass of `Observable` so you can apply the usual `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, etc. operators available.

For example, if you want to sum the `qty`s of the grouped `Foo`s per each `Bar`, you can map the `GroupedObservable` in this way:

```
Observable.fromIterable(foos)
    .groupBy(foo -> foo.getBar().getId())
    .flatMapSingle(grouped -> grouped.map(foo -> foo.qty).reduce(0, Integer::sum))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```